# ReactJS content not filing up the whole page and is only taking up 3/4 of the available height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-particles-js

As you can see the div that contains the particles and the Home component is only using up 3/4 of the height even when the height attribute is 100%. Am I rendering the component wrong, what should i do so the component fills up the whole page.

I think the problem is the ParticlesComponent as it is not taking the full available width for some reason.

App.js:

```
  return (
     <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        }}
      >
        <ParticlesComponent />
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
          }}
        >
          <Home/>
        </div>
      </div>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

Particle Component:

```
export default () => (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundPosition: "50% 50%"

      }}
    >
      <Particles
        // unrelated particle code that I decided to remove so that it doesn't clog up the page
      />
      
    </div>
  );
```

**UPDATE**

How I managed to solve it

I added this to the index.html file:

```
#tsparticles{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.body-particles{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: You've only set the height of the parent container. Are you *actually* using `particle.js`, or are you using `react-particles-js`? Can you updated your question to include the `ParticlesComponent` component code?

Comment: Since you provided just an image, it's hard to understand what's wrong in our case. Can you please share the actual website or the codebase?

Comment: @DrewReese Yea, Im using react-particles-js. I added the code. Is the styling of the div wrong in the particle component?

Comment: @Constantin Hi, sorry about that, I have just added the full code base on GitHub: https://github.com/TanushN/portfolio. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to inspect element, `heigth:100%` is depends on the height of parent element's height, make sure your parent element's is full height.

Comment: @RapSherlock Your right it looks canvas of the particles is the problem here, it is not taking 100% width and 100% even I though I specified it to do.                                         Insepect Element picture for more details: [Picture](https://imgur.com/a/kHwFQMZ)

Comment: You need to check all parent element and make sure that height is set correctly 100% or if you don't care about all display on your container just set using Viewport Height (vh) `height: 100vh`, with `fixed` or `absolute` position to the element do you want to full height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I managed to solve it

I added this to the index.html file:

```js
#tsparticles{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.body-particles{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this in particle.js, line 15

```
<Particles
        style={{
          minHeight: '100vh'
        }}
```

This should do it.

Optional: you have a lot of position absolute all over the place, I would remove most and add styles to the

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height 100%
```

And make sure to install all the dependencies, because you will not be able to deploy it. (*react-particles-js, semantic-ui-cs*s). Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

The `Particles` component takes [props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js#props).

What seems to work well is specifying the `className` prop for the wrapper and setting `width` and `height` to `100%`.

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Particles

```
<Particles className="wrapper" />
```

This allows the `Particles` component to take the full height and width of any containing element.

[image: Edit react-particles-js full width & height]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but I managed to fix this issue by manually adding some css to the tsparticles canvas through index.html file.

Comment: @TanushN `Particles` takes `width` and `height` props, as well as a `style` prop that supposedly is to the canvas element, and there is also a `canvasClassName` to directly set a classname on the canvas element. TBH, this is a pretty cool module but not very user friendly nor documented well IMO.

Comment: I created a template on codesandox with full screen Particles some weeks ago: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tsparticles-dw43f About documentation there's a lot to read on `react-particles-js` core: `tsParticles`